# How to start Screen Recording as soon as my application is turned on?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a screen recording program using encoder 4. 
I want my program to start recording as soon as I open the window. Here is what I have so far:

But I keep getting an error saying : No Overload for "App_Activated" matches delegate 'System.EventHandler"

Thanks for all the help.

```
<Window x:Class="ScreenCapture.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Screen Capture" 
    Activated="App_Activated"
    Closing="OnClose"
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    Height="76" Width="99" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"                             WindowStyle="ToolWindow">


protected void App_Activated(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Size monitorSize = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize;
        Rectangle capRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, monitorSize.Width, monitorSize.Height);
        job.CaptureRectangle = capRect;
        job.OutputPath = @"C:\output\ScreenCap";
        job.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared it with the right signature, it should be  `void App_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: It doesn't work. its saying type or namepsace EventArgs could not be found

Comment: its a core class in .NET, to use it, you just need :- using System;